# Subject and Complement Agreement

Tags: grammar

Make us a good human!

Make us good humans!

They considered themselves a god.

They considered themselves gods.

Which one is grammatical? I think if the subject is plural the complement should also be plural.

Comment: The first one is valid as a request to have a good human made *for* the speaker (by a god, or an IVF technician?), and the third one is valid as a "singular **they**" construction. So they're ***all*** "grammatical", in their different ways.

Comment: "Make" and "consider" do not here have a distributional sense, so plural predicatives are normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Make us a good human!
> 2. Make us good humans!
> 3. They considered themselves a god.
> 4. They considered themselves gods.

Edit

#1 has the construction
**subject (understood) + ditransitive verb + indirect object + direct object**.  The speakers request, say, for a baby who will grow up to be a good human.

#2 to #4 have the construction
**subject + complex transitive verb + direct object + object complement**.  The subject in #2 is understood.

In #2, the speakers want someone to change them into good humans.   We have agreement in number, plural object with plural complement.

In #4, we have agreement in number, all plural.

In #3, both *They* and *themselves* are singular, like that used for a gender-neutral third-person.